# AVL tree size in terms of height

Tags: balanced-search-trees

For AVL trees, which one of the following is possible as the tree size (expressed in term of the tree height h)? Recall that the size of a tree is the number of nodes in the tree.

A. $Θ(h^{2.1})$
B. $Θ(1.1^h)$
C. $Θ(1.9^h)$
D. $Θ(2.1^h)$

---

So this question came up on my midterm and I don't understand why the answer is C and not D.
How I solved it is:
$h=log(n)$
so $n=2^h$.
Does it have anything to do with the fact that it's asking for a tight bound?

Comment: No binary tree can have more than $2.0^h$ elements. Only perfectly balanced trees with "enough" nodes reach that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n$ be the size of an AVL tree with height $h$. Then we have
$$ \log_2(n+1) \leq h \leq c\log_2(n+2) + b$$
where $c\approx 1.44$ and $b\approx -0.328$. So, 
$$ 0.8(1.6)^h\lt df^h=2^{-b/c}\left(2^{1/c}\right)^h=2^{(h-b)/c}-2 \leq n \leq 2^h -1 \lt 2^h $$
where $d\approx 0.85$ and $f\approx 1.618$.

Now you can see that the only number among 1.1, 1.9 and 2.1 that is between 1.6 and 2 is 1.9. Hence the answer is C.

I would not say it is asking for a tight bound.